# Angular 2 - Date Pipe, Time Conversion HH:mm to 2 Decimal Places

Tags: datetime, angular

I am using Angular 2, trying to convert a date object to HH:mm date format, with minutes to two decimal places, but when I use this:

```
{{date | date:"HH:mm"}}
```

I get 15:0 instead of 15:00.

I tried look at Angular 2 documentation but it's relatively limit so far, would appreciate any guidance about this and whether it is how Angular 2 formats time by default.

Comment: Possibly this bug: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/9338

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the documentation your usage is correct:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-class.html

- `mm` should result in a 2-digit format.

Are you using the most recent version?

The documentation also says `Stability: Experimental`. This might still be a bug.

Comment: I'm using ^2.0.0-rc.2, I can try rc3

Comment: As Stefan and Assylias have indicated, this was indeed a bug in Angular rc2, which was fixed last week. When upgrading to rc3, this  worked like a charm.

Comment: Also the date object should be standard: https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Answer (score 0):

You could use
`date : 'shortTime'` or `date :'h:mm a'` to get a result of this format `9:03 AM`